# Creating a 2D array containing values of intensities from a set of 3 1-D vectors

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, vectorization

My apologies if the title seems vague, but I tried my best. In any case, I have a dataframe with three columns, one containing datetime values (for time of observation), another containing the range (distance from instrument at which the observation was made), and the last containing the intensity of the observations. The scatter plot for this data is shown below:

[image]

I need to filter out the random isolated 'salt and pepper' observations, and plan to use a median filter to do this. However, I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried to create a 2D array containing intensity values indexed according to the time and range. So 00:00 UT corresponds to row 0 and 0 km corresponds to column 0 and so on... empty positions contain NaNs. I then apply the median filter (scipy's medfilt: scipy.ndimage.median_filter) to this 2D array.

My issue is that it seems inefficient, as I'm having to loop over large series of data to create the array. And, of course, converting the filtered 2D array to a corresponding 1D series is difficult.

Here's the code I am using to obtain a 2D array

```
def get2DData(df, filt_size):
    '''
    Implementing this method: We want a 2D array that stores all the LoS 
    velocities, so that we can ultimately apply median filtering to it. 
    
    To do this, iterate over all unique datetime values and all unique range values, 
    assigning LoS velocity values to the appropriate positions in a 2D array.
    '''
    
    arr = np.empty((len(df['time'].unique()), len(df['slist'].unique()), ))
    arr[:] = np.nan
    
    times_ = sorted(df['time'].unique())
    times_index = np.arange(len(times_))
    
    range_ = sorted(df['slist'].unique())
    range_index = np.arange(len(range_))
    
    times_dict = {A: B for A, B in zip(times_, times_index)}
    range_dict = {A: B for A, B in zip(range_, range_index)}
    
    times_dict_rev = {A: B for A, B in zip(times_index, times_)}
    range_dict_rev = {A: B for A, B in zip(range_index, range_)}
    
    for dt, rng_, v in zip(df['time'].values, df['slist'].values, df['v'].values):
        arr[times_dict[dt]][range_dict[rng_]] = v
    
    medfilt_arr = applyFilt(arr,filt_size)
    
    dt_list = []
    rng_list = []
    v_list = []
    for ix,iy in np.ndindex(medfilt_arr.shape):
        dt_list.append(times_dict_rev[ix])
        rng_list.append(range_dict_rev[iy])
        v_list.append(medfilt_arr[ix][iy])
    
    df_filtered = pd.DataFrame({'time': dt_list, 'slist': rng_list,'v': v_list})
    
    return arr, df_filtered
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your goal is to compute the median intensity across all the ranges, for each time step? And to do so you try to find an efficient way to build the 2d array?

Comment: Yes! That seems accurate, although I don't think I would be computing intensity across ALL ranges for each timestep. I am using a 3x3 median filter (for now). But the most important part is building the 2d array, yes.

Comment: If we could see the code you have tried it might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accelerate the creation of the array could be

```
def get2DArray(df):
    alltime = df['time'].to_numpy()
    allrange = df['slist'].to_numpy()

    unique_time = np.unique(alltime)
    unique_rang = np.unique(allrange)

    row = unique_time.searchsorted(alltime)
    col = unique_rang.searchsorted(allrange)

    arr = np.full((len(unique_time), len(unique_rang)), fill_value=np.NaN)
    arr[row, col] = df["v"].to_numpy()

    return arr
```

The idea is use the relative position of the time and range in all the possibles values to find the associated row/col, instead of using a dictionary. On some tests that I did, this version was ~5-7 times faster, which is not that much but it's nice already